# JS контекст вложенных функций

Tags: javascript

просьба объяснить, по возможности более доходчиво, не могу понять как это работает.
Вот кусок кода

```
function makeCounter() {
  let count = 0;

  return function() {
    return count++;
  };
}
```

Каждый последующий вызов будет инкрементировать переменную count и возвращать ее. Почему каждый вызов функции не будет переобъявлять переменную count по новой и присваивать значение 0?
Благодарю заранее.

Comment: https://medium.com/@stasonmars/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-javascript-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-c211805b6898

Comment: После слова "вызов" пропущено указание - вызов чего. Каждый вызов `makeCounter` будет переобъявлять переменную `count`.

Comment: Каждый вызов возвращенной анонимной функции, сохраненной во внешнюю переменную, будет увеличивать переменную `count` из вызова `makeCounter`, вернувшего анонимную функцию, сохраненную во внешнюю переменную.